# image not recognized in the project folder

Tags: c++, opencv

When i specify the destination folder path of a image in my open cv project it works fine but when i keep that image in the project folder the image is not recognized.
 i tried to run the following sample code

```
include "opencv\cv.h"      // include it to used Main OpenCV functions.
#include "opencv\highgui.h" //include it to use GUI functions.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "Desert.jpg" ); //change the name (image.jpg) according to your Image filename.
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
    return 0;
}
```

when i specify `C:\Users\mia\Desktop\Desert.jpg` problem is solved.

Comment: oh please, DON'T use the deprecated c-api any more. (and yes, on win, if you start it from the ide, your prog does *not* start from your project folder but from debug or release)

Comment: I am a beginner in open cv and visual studio so please can you explain me what is meant by program starting from debug or release.

Answer (score 0):

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "Desert.jpg" );
```

It's because you're using relative path here. If so, you should put the image in your `TargetDir` (the directory where your program are supposed to generated into).

---

**P.S.:** As commented by @berak, you should use the new OpenCV's API (e.g. use `Mat` instead of `IplImage *`).

Comment: actually i am running the code of someones else written in old c-api so i have to use it.Also i have tested it keeping in the targetdir but problem is not solved.Only specifying the image path solves errors.